# Appropriate prior for Bayesian inference of classical fields given data

Tags: field-theory, statistics

Suppose I want to infer the configuration of a function $q(t)$ with $t \in \Omega$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$, given a dataset $d=[\{t_1, q_1 \}, ..., \{ t_N,q_N \}]$, where $q_i \equiv q(t_i) $. Suppose further I know the dynamics of the field, for instance $q(t)$ is assumed to obey the equation of the anharmonic oscillator

$$\left( \frac{d^2}{dt^2} + \omega^2\right)q(t)=g q^3(t),$$

deriving from a Hamiltonian

$$H(p,q) = \frac{p^2}{2}+\omega^2\frac{q^2}{2}+\frac{g}{4}q^4.$$

First, note that in this case I can just use two data points and solve the equation, but that's just peculiar to the dimensionality of the problem (if this was a field theory and I just had scattered data, that wouldn't work).

The natural way to do this statistically would be to use Bayes' theorem

$$\mathcal{P}[q(t) | d] = \frac{\mathcal{P}[d | q(t)] \mathcal{P}[q(t)]}{Z_d},$$

where

$$Z_d=\int \mathcal{D}q(t)\mathcal{P}[d | q(t)].$$

Here we need to make certain assumptions about the prior probability $\mathcal{P}[q(t)]$, and this is where the knowledge about the field dynamics fits in. The question is: what is the appropriate prior that captures our knowledge of the field dynamics?

One idea might come from the following: rewrite the numerator of the left hand side as

$$\mathcal{P}[d | q(t)] \mathcal{P}[q(t)]=e^{-\mathcal{H}[q(t),d]}$$

where the Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}[q(t),d]$ is defined as $\mathcal{H}[q(t),d]= - \log (\mathcal{P}[d | q(t)])$ and is hence broken into two additive factors, $\mathcal{H}[d|q(t)]$ and $\mathcal{H}[q(t)]$.

Comment: Prior usually depends on a specific problem... or one takes a non-informative prior, which may be a non-trivial thing in this case. Frankly, I am not sure whether the Bayesian approach is really necessary, but the problem is not fully clear to me...

Comment: If the field is in some kind of thermal equilibrium with an environment at temperature $T$, the canonical ensemble & the Boltzmann distribution might be a good prior to adopt.  And if $g$ is "small", it just reduces to a normal distribution for $q$.